# Test methods executed which is are mentioned in test suite xml

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have an issue while executing a test suite. Some of the test methods are automatically executed even though they are not specified in test suite. I am using TestNG + WebDriver

Here I have two test methods:

- `verifyContentOnSignUpScreen`
- `verifyLinkPresentOnFooterSection`

In my test suite I have only mentioned `verifyContentOnSignUpScreen` but when executing the suite both test methods are executed. I am unable to find the mistake in my suite and test methods.

Test Suite:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="regressionSuite" parallel="none">

  <parameter name="ApplicationOpt" value="web"></parameter>
  <parameter name="userEmailAddress"value="xxxxx@gmail.com"></parameter>


  <test name="Test">    
    <classes>
        <!-- Sign and Login Module -->
      <class name="Tests.Login.LoginApp"/>
        <method>
            <include name="verifyContentOnSignUpScreen"></include>
            <include name="verifyLinkPresentOnFooterSection"></include> 

        </method>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- regressionSuite -->
```

Test Class:

```
    package Tests.Login;

    public class LoginApp extends UtilProject{

        // UI Login screen
        UILoginApp UiLoginAp = new UILoginApp();

        // Data Login module 
        TestData.Login.DataLoginApp dataLogin = new TestData.Login.DataLoginApp();

        // Action Login app
        ActionLoginApp actLogin = new ActionLoginApp();

        // Navigate Login Login App
        NavigationLoginApp naviLogin = new NavigationLoginApp();

        //Web Navigation
        NavigationWeb naviWeb = new NavigationWeb();

        //Create Instance of Extent report
        ExtentReports extentRep = extentReportGenerator(this.getClass().getName());

        //Email utility 
        emailUtility emailUti = new emailUtility();

        //Navigation Sign up 
        final static NavigationSingUp navigSignup = new NavigationSingUp();

        final static UIcustomerSignUp UisignUP = new UIcustomerSignUp();

        //Verify the content on the Sign Up screen (priority=0)
        /**
         * Verify content on Web User sign In screen
         */
        @Test
        public void verifyContentOnSignUpScreen(){
            try {
                extentRep.startTest("Verify contnet on the Login and Sign Up screen");
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(UiLoginAp.UiEleStrtNow));
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(UiLoginAp.UiloginScreenImgSlider));
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(UiLoginAp.UiloginScreenCodeInput));
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(UiLoginAp.UiloginScreenCodeButton));
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(UiLoginAp.UiLoginScreenHeaderSection));
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(UiLoginAp.UiLoginScreenHeaderSignUpAnSignIn));
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//img[@class='sliderVideo']"))).click();

                driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("iframeDemoVideo")));
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(UiLoginAp.UiloginScreenMediaPlay)).click();
                driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(UiLoginAp.UiloginScreenMediaClose)).click();
                extentRep.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Expected content is present on sign in and sin up screen ");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                extentRep.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Conent on the Sign Up screen is not appeared correctly");
                extentRep.endTest();
                e.printStackTrace();
                Assert.fail();
            }
        }
    @Test
    public void verifyLinkPresentOnFooterSection(){
        try {
            System.out.println("verifyLinkPresentOnFooterSection");
            extentRep.startTest("Verify Privacy Policy,Terms of Service and Give Feedback link on footer section is working or not");
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(UiLoginAp.UiLoginFooterSectonLinkPrivacyPolicy)).click();
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(UiLoginAp.UiLoginFooterSectionPopupClose)).click();

            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(UiLoginAp.UiLoginFooterSectonLinkTermOfService)).click();
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(UiLoginAp.UiLoginFooterSectionPopupClose)).click();

            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(UiLoginAp.UiLoginFooterSectonLinkGiveFeebBack));
            extentRep.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Verify Privacy Policy,Terms of Service and Give Feedback link on footer section is working");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            extentRep.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Links on sign / Sign up screen is not present");
            extentRep.endTest();
            e.printStackTrace();
            Assert.fail();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I want something quick solution for this ..it wild be good help

Answer (score 1):

What is the wrong here? in testng.xml file included both methods, so both are executed. below example helps you to exclude the method in class - note the tag in the second include is now an exclude.

```
 <test name="Test1">
 <classes>
   <class name="Tests.Login.LoginApp">
  <methods>
    <include name="verifyContentOnSignUpScreen"/>
    <exclude name="verifyLinkPresentOnFooterSection"/>
  </methods>
 </class>
 </classes>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree if we use exclude under method tag. I have another solution -

**Remove "methods" tag from "class"**

- Do not include any method under  with prefix "include"
- While writing code use can use those methods which you really wanted to use

Hope this helps !